# sfdx force:source:deploy throws "INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to deploy config only changes (only a permission set change) and while running:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml -u Prod
```

I get the error:

> INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations

Whereas when I convert the metadata from the Source format to Mdapi format and then try to run:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir mdapi --targetusername Prod
```

It runs successfully without asking me to run tests.

Why this difference in the behavior between source:deploy and mdapi:deploy? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With both `force:mdapi:deploy` and `force:source:deploy`, there is a parameter to specify the test level (`-l` or `--testlevel`).

Looking through [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force.htm), it seems like both should be using the "NoTestRun" level (since you're not including apex or triggers) though it is possible that there is a discrepancy between how the mdapi command is run and how the source command is run. This behavior suggests that either:

- The force:mdapi:deploy command is actually running with the "RunLocalTests" test level
- The force:source:deploy command is incorrectly applying a check for the test level when no apex/triggers are being deployed

The metadata api also changed for api >= v34.0. Prior to v34.0, [local tests were run when deploying a permissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) (same with a handful of other metadata types).

There is also [a github issue on the sfdc cli project that seems to be almost word for word a match for your issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/257), which contains a nifty workaround. Simply use the "RunSpecificTests" test level, and provide a test name that does not exist as a test class (it seems like using an Apex class name works, but that's not something I'd suggest doing) in your target org.

Something like `sfdx force:source:deploy -m PermissionSet:myPermSetName -u Production -l RunSpecifiedTests -r notATest`

Comment: The mdapi actually is kind of buggy, if I recall correctly; it often requires more than NoTestRun even when you're not deploying actual code. I don't think this is a CLI problem, but an API problem. It'd be interesting to see what the Deploy Status screen reads when running force:source:deploy.